# How to extract data from a file

Tags: xml

Hey everyone, I have a file with info like the below. I want to extract the numbers out of the records. Can some one give me an awk or a sed oneliner if possible? Maybe out put to a file? This would really help me out. I am on ubuntu so I have linux utilities.

Thanks a lot.

```
<product_id>101747</product_id>
<product_id>2847549</product_id>
<product_id>149833</product_id>
<product_id>123380</product_id>
<product_id>66334</product_id>
<product_id>66475</product_id>
<product_id>123387</product_id>
<product_id>6266040</product_id>
<product_id>3480755</product_id>
<product_id>6529572</product_id>
<product_id>22852</product_id>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python oneliner:

```
python -c "import re;print('\n'.join(re.findall('([0-9]+)',open('infile.txt').read())))" > outfile.txt
```

Change infile.txt and outfile.txt.

Example output:

```
101747
2847549
149833
123380
66334
66475
123387
6266040
3480755
6529572
22852
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It worked! Could you please explain in a few words how it extracted it? I guess if you could break this down....                                             re;print('\n'.join(re.findall('([0-9]+)',open('infile.txt').read())))  Thanks a lot for the answer....Now I can go back to my work!!

Comment: `import re;` imports the regex module, `print('\n'.join(...))` prints out each element in the list `...` joined by a newline and `...` is `re.findall('([0-9]+)', open('infile.txt').read())` which opens `infile.txt` and reads all characters out of it. Finally we do a `[0-9]+` regex on it extracting all the numbers creating the list which is then joined and printed. Please don't forget to accept my answer if it worked :)

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation and all the help. I really appreciate it. This was wonderful intro to python scripting for me.